# Parent menu link opens children when clicked, instead of going to link (Drupal)

Tags: html, css, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-8

I have created a Menu in Drupal and the structure look like this:

[image: menu picture]
A parent link with children. In my website it looks like this:

[image]

Note that "products" takes you to `/products`. However, when I click on it, it just opens the children menu links:

[image]

Instead of taking me to `/products`, it justs expands. The structure of the menu is such:

```
<li class="expanded dropdown open">                                                                            
      <a href="/products" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/370" aria-expanded="true">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="first">
              <a href="/product/inconcert" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/362">InConcert</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="/product/voicempower" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/363">VoiceMPower</a>
          </li>
          ....
     </ul>
</li>
```

As I can Imagine, the problem is that the `<li>` gets triggered when I click on it, instead of the `<a>` that is inside.

How can I fix this issue? Maybe it is possible to open the menus on hover, and when I click to take me to the link??

Answer (score 1):

I finally worked it out. I just needed to edit the `menu.html.twig` file from Bootstrap's templates. I just removed `data-toggle` from the `setAttribute()` function as so:

From:

```
{% set link_attributes = link_attributes.addClass('dropdown-toggle').setAttribute('data-toggle', 'dropdown') %}
```

To:

```
 {% set link_attributes = link_attributes.addClass('dropdown-toggle').setAttribute('', 'dropdown') %}
```

This removed the opening of the dropdown. And the next step was to open the dropdown by hovering. This was relatively easy, I just put this CSS code:

```
li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
  @media (min-width: 979px) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I don't know if this is the best or correct way to do it, but for me it worked.